# git nested projects

Tags: git, github, nested, git-submodules

I've a stable and functioning project `X`. I want a module to be added to it and that's is from some other project `Y` on github in my `modules` directory.

I've `git remote add Y git@github.neel/Y.git` followed by `git fetch Y`
But there there is nothing on `Y` directory yet . I followed http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html
and also did the checkout but still the directory is empty

I don't want to break my existing project for submoduling have I already done anything wrong with it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands you ran were as if `Y` was a clone of `X`, which is not the case.

Instead you have to register it as a submodule of `X`, with `git submodule add`, and check them out with `git submodule init --update`

```
git submodule add git@github.neel/Y.git modules/Y
git submodule init --update
```

Comment: Well I've already executed `remote add` commands and then I did a `reset --hard` would that suffice ? or its currently screwed up ?

Comment: `reset --hard` won't have any effect on remotes you added, and shouldn't be executed lightly :) `git remote rm Y` is what you want

Comment: Is that everything I need to do to to rollback ?